# Disable simultaneous document editing (when implementing a WOPI server)

Tags: ms-office, ms-wopi

I have a WOPI server, implemented more or less according to http://wopi.readthedocs.io/ (without "cobalt", i.e. using the 2016 version of office online)

The problem: two users can open the same document at the same time for editing.

How do I prevent that from happening?
I've checked the docs. There was a flag "supportsCoAuthoring", but it's not there anymore, and anyways it's set to false. I don't want support co-authoring.

I thought that office online has an in-built support for that, so that it will not allow 2 people to edit the same document at the same time (i.e. if the server "Lock" returns 409, "conflict"). But this does not seem to be the case - my file opens for editing for both users now just fine, even if there is a lock conflict! And the last who saves wins. Am I missing something..?

If we have 2 users, say, A, and B, then when B opens document for editing (already opened by A), then A gets a nice popup "User B also started editing this document". I don't want that. Instead I want B to be not able to open the document for editing.

Should locks be implemented separately instead (purely by the server)?

The code is based on https://github.com/apulliam/WOPIFramework (without sql part though, as I don't need/have any sql)

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement not only the `Lock`-related operations on the WOPI server but also all the related responses.

E.g. when you implement `PutFile`:

> If the file is currently locked and the X-WOPI-Lock value does not match the lock currently on the file the host must return a “lock mismatch” response (409 Conflict) and include an X-WOPI-Lock response header containing the value of the current lock on the file. In the case where the file is unlocked, the host must set X-WOPI-Lock to the empty string.

See the documentation [here](http://wopi.readthedocs.io/projects/wopirest/en/latest/files/PutFile.html?highlight=putfile) and [here](http://wopi.readthedocs.io/projects/wopirest/en/latest/concepts.html#term-lock).

Comment: Dear rocky, that's what I'm doing.. Thanks to you for the reference and samples btw- really helps :) A question - should the office web apps server prevent other user from editing file, or should it not? That is, if I return 409 Conflict?

Comment: My guess is that it should as there is no point in letting the user edit the document while it can't be saved in the end. I'd have to test it and I don't have it running on my machine at the moment. Nevertheless, the WOPI server should prevent overwriting the changes by returning 409s when a lock is in place.